# Contextual bookmarks bar

Tags: google-chrome-extension, bookmarks

I'm wondering if there is a good contextual bookmarks bar out there - e.g. When I'm on google.com, I see different bookmarks than when I navigate to nytimes.com.

Just trying to get a sense before building my own - I had no luck googling for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

To help you started, you can refer from this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks):

> Use the `chrome.bookmarks` API to create, organize, and otherwise
>   manipulate bookmarks. Also see [Override Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override), which you can use
>   to create a custom Bookmark Manager page.

You can follow the whole process in the documentation.

Examples are also provided, see sample snippet below.

> The following code creates a folder with the title "Extension
>   bookmarks". The first argument to `create()` specifies properties for
>   the new folder. The second argument defines a function to be executed
>   after the folder is created.
>
> ```
>   chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': bookmarkBar.id,
>                            'title': 'Extension bookmarks'},
>                           function(newFolder) {
>     console.log("added folder: " + newFolder.title);
>   });
> ```
>
> The next snippet creates a bookmark pointing to the developer
>   documentation for extensions. Since nothing bad will happen if
>   creating the bookmark fails, this code doesn't bother to define a
>   callback function.
>
> ```
>  chrome.bookmarks.create({'parentId': extensionsFolderId,
>                                'title': 'Extensions doc',
>                                'url': 'http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions'});
> ```

You can refer from these [basic samples](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/chrome/common/extensions/docs/examples/api/bookmarks/basic/) and [other samples](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) for reference.